# One to one and Onto Fuctions

Tags: analysis, functions

Let $A$ and $B$ be two non-empty sets. Prove that there exists a function $f: A \to B$ that is $1$ to $1$ iff there exists a function $g: B \to A$ that is onto.

I understand why it is true but I'm finding it really difficult to put in proper proof words, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If there exist onto function $g$ then $\forall y\in A\exists x\in B: g(x)=y$ this implies that $|B|\ge |A|$. Let's create the set $B'=\min\{x: y\in A, g(x)=y\}$.

What I did is creating a new set $B'\subseteq  B$ such that the function $g$ with $g: B'\to A$ is bijective function.

If $g$ with the new domain is bijective than I can find $g^{-1}: A\to B'$ that is also bijective, set $f(x)=g^{-1}(x)$.

The function $f(x)$ will be never be ${B'}^c$ where ${B'}^c$ is what in $B$ and not in $B'$

---

The other way around:

---

If exists one to one function $f$ then $\forall x,x'\in A: f(x)=f(x')\implies x=x'$.

Now the inverse function $f^{-1}$ is a function that maps some items in $B$, let's call this subset $B'$, to all the items in $A$.

the function $f^{-1}$ in the domain of $B'$ is bijective, so by setting $g$ to be: $g(y)=f^{-1}(y)$ where $y\in B'$ and $g(y)=$ random value in $A$ when $y\in {B'}^c$ where ${B'}^c$ is what in $B$ and not in $B'$, we are done

Answer (score 0):

If $g:B\rightarrow A$ is onto, then for every $a\in A$ there is some $b\in B$ such that $g(b)=a$. What should $f(a)$ be then? (Maybe there's more than one; that's OK, just pick any one of them.)

Comment: Just a quick question - how does one make a consistent 'pick'? Could you, perhaps, illustrate this with an example involving sets with infinite elements? I am getting this nagging feeling that a consistent pick in some cases could be a non-trivial task.

Comment: @SystematicDisintegration What you're asking is essentially the contents of the "Axiom of Choice" - which is usually taken to be true, though as your intuition indicated, it's not exactly an axiom which is completely without controversy.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Thanks for confirming; that was exactly what I was thinking, but I was hesitant to reference it.